# Explain println and print statement after a loop has been executed in Java?

Tags: java, println

What happens here, that is when print is used, why will it not print where the line stops?

```
for(int i = 0; i <=2; i++){
System.out.println(i)
System.out.print("s");
}
```

Why will it not print the s after 2 like this:

0

1

2s

From what i learnt, someone said it will buffer for ever? What does that mean? The computer will know to print the letter s beside 2 because it has stopped there, so why not print?

Comment: The code won't even compile as there's no semi-colon on the line containing println().

Comment: You're correct, yes it was a slight mistake on my side, but the question concept is eaasily understood

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually `print` prints the `s` where the line stops!. The problem here is, `println` already put a new line first, and then `print` starts from that place.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a semi-colon after the first statement in your loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i <=2; i++) {
    System.out.println(i);
    System.out.print("s");
}
```

The above code will output this:

0
s1
s2
s

However if you do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i <=2; i++) {
    System.out.print(i);
    System.out.println("s");
}
```

Which will print the following:

0s
1s
2s

With an extra line break at the end.

Answer (score 1):

For each iteration in the loop, the code prints the integer, adds a newline (since `println` is used) and prints the s. So you will have an output like

> 0
>
> s1
>
> s2
>
> s

Answer (score 0):

What happens with you code:

```
0
s1 
s2
s
```

Why it happens:
if you use

```
print("s");
```

the program will print "s" and thats it.
if you use:

```
println("s");
```

you'll get a new line after each "s" which I suppose is what you seek.

Answer (score 0):

It is because println will leave new line character(\n) at the end of the statement, not at the beginning of the statement.

Answer (score 0):

Both statements are in the same loop so will run one after another.

So:

```
System.out.println(i);
```

will give i(whatever that variable is) then a new line.

```
System.out.print("s");
```

will print "s".  With no new line.

Your output will be

```
0
s1
s2
s
```

And since your only want an output on the last iteration of the loop, you need an 'if':

```
    for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
        System.out.print(i);
        if (i == 2) {
        System.out.print("s");
        } else {
        System.out.println("");
        }
    }
```

Which gives:

```
0
1
2s
```

Answer (score 0):

The actual answer is that the previous println already puts it to the next line. Using System.out.print("s") actually goes horizontally forever, therefore it never prints.